# Loop through Pandas rolling sum (To get the sum of last 100)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, cumulative-sum, rolling-computation

I have the following data:

```
Date        Qty
01/01/2019  4.15
02/01/2019  12.39
03/01/2019  14.15
04/01/2019  12.15
05/01/2019  3.26
06/01/2019  6.23
07/01/2019  15.89
08/01/2019  5.55
09/01/2019  12.49
10/01/2019  9.4
11/01/2019  9.11
12/01/2019  9.18
13/01/2019  13.45
14/01/2019  4.52
15/01/2019  0
16/01/2019  0
17/01/2019  8.41
18/01/2019  9.55
19/01/2019  15.43
20/01/2019  16.45
21/01/2019  9.28
22/01/2019  9.55
23/01/2019  7.87
24/01/2019  12.58
25/01/2019  6.12
26/01/2019  6.15
27/01/2019  6.07
28/01/2019  15.53
```

The output that I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
Date        Window_Sum
01/01/2019  
02/01/2019  
03/01/2019  
04/01/2019  
05/01/2019  
06/01/2019  
07/01/2019  
08/01/2019  
09/01/2019  
10/01/2019  
11/01/2019  100.62
12/01/2019  109.8
13/01/2019  110.86
14/01/2019  101.23
15/01/2019  101.23
16/01/2019  101.23
17/01/2019  109.64
18/01/2019  103.78
19/01/2019  112.98
20/01/2019  107.99
21/01/2019  104.78
22/01/2019  104.93
23/01/2019  103.69
24/01/2019  107.09
25/01/2019  113.21
26/01/2019  101.39
27/01/2019  107.46
28/01/2019  105.03
```

Let me just briefly explain the logic to get the output: 
So on 01/01/2019, the Qty is 4.15, and looking back there are no other values, so the cumulative sum is not greater than 100. Hence, the output value is a NULL.

Fast forward to 10/01/2019, the Qty is 9.4, and looking back the cumulative sum is 95.66. Since the cumulative sum is not greater than 100, the output will be a NULL value.

Next, we'll look at 11/01/2019. The Qty here is 9.11, and looking back the cumulative sum is 100.62. Reason why it is 100.62 and not 104.77 is because the sum of Qty from 11/01/2019 to 02/01/2019 (looking backwards), hits 100/slightly above 100 first.

Similarly, at 12/01/2019, the Qty here is 9.18, and looking back the cumulative sum is 100.8 because the sum of Qty from 12/01/2019 to 02/01/2019(looking backwards), hits 100/slightly above 100 first.

Is there a solution which allows a loop into the pandas rolling sum function to achieve this result?

What I'm trying to achieve here is to ensure that once the cumulative sum reaches 100 or slightly over 100,  then I will take the value and append it into the "Window_Sum".

**Update: Managed to get the code running with help. Here's the solution:**

```
#get last row index
start=len(data)-1

#initialise cumulative sum
cumsum = 0

for i in range(start,-1,-1):
    j=i
    while cumsum < 100:
        cumsum +=  data.loc[j,'Qty']
        if j!=0:
            j-=1
        else: 
            cumsum=None
            break

    data.loc[i,'Window_Sum']=cumsum
    cumsum=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `cumsum()` function:

```
In [7]: df['Window_Sum'] = df['Qty'].cumsum()

In [8]: df.head()
Out[8]:
        Date  Qty  Window_Sum
0  01-Jan-19  4.0         4.0
1  02-Jan-19  1.0         5.0
2  03-Jan-19  6.0        11.0
3  04-Jan-19  3.0        14.0
4  05-Jan-19  3.0        17.0
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Hi, what I'm trying to achieve here is to ensure that once the cumulative sum reaches 100 or slightly over 100,  then I will take the value and append it into the "Window_Sum".

Comment: I missed that part, but it's still unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve. Do you mind editing the question to clarify, and maybe use a smaller dataset (like 5-10 rows) as an example?

Comment: I think I am beginning to understand. You need a window cumulative sum with a constant lookback?

Comment: Hi, yes. I need to find the optimal window for the rolling sum such that once the cumulative sum reaches 100 or slightly over 100, I will take the value and append it into a new col "Window_Sum" for that specific date period.

Comment: I still don't completely follow. What do you mean by "append"? Can you edit the question to demonstrate a similar thing with a smaller data set?

Comment: Hi, have edited the question. Thanks for taking the time to help. :)